# Raspberry Pi will not boot

Tags: boot

I have booted my Raspberry Pi a few times, and it worked fine, but now it scrolls and loads settings but stops and asks for a password. I have not set one; my university gave me the OS on a 4 GB SD card already loaded.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Most distributions have a default password.  If that does not work, you can mount the filesystem on another linux box and null the password.  Or you can re-image the SD card.

Comment: Ask your Uni what the password is.

Answer (score 4):

If the distribution is Raspbian, then the default username is `pi` and the password is `raspberry`.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the SD card if there is not anything important there. Follow the instructions here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md.

Or you press shift and hold when the picture of a big raspberry shows up, and it will let you install Raspbian or another OS again.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about the settings the rasp shows you.

If it doesn't ask you for the user, you can try to put any word in the password to trigger the incorrect user/password message because it will show you again to enter the user and password.

Other method of login you can use is to press ctrl + alt + F2 (for example) and try to login from another terminal.

Answer (score -1):

USERNAME:pi PASS: raspberry if using raspiban

Comment: -_- Lol me. I was in too much of a rush...